# Issue with Magento Review module

Tags: magento2

I was disabled Magento Review with command

```
"bin/magento module:enable Magento_Review"
```

Now, I reenabled it with the same command, but the module appears anywhere.

No admin links under Reports, Marketing->User Content and Stores->Attributes.

It's enabled by settings too under Stores->Settings->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Product Reviews

Also there no issues with source files under

/vendor/magento/module-review

/vendor/magento/module-review-analytics

/generated/code/Magento/Review

Comment: Which magento version you are using?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.3.4

Comment: "bin/magento module:enable Magento_Review". You couldnt disable this module using `enable` comand...  If you used exactly this command "bin/magento module:enable Magento_Review", magento_review wasl allways enabled but never showed up on frontend. Maybe try enable this functionality on admin? (ok, I see its enabled. Clear cache etc). If wont work, it is probably hide in some phtml files (may depends on theme youa re using)

Comment: It's not working with  luma theme. Also it doesn't matter with admincp?

Comment: I have disabled "Add Secret Key to URLs" option and added "review/rating/index" path to admin url now i am able to access review pages but they are empty.



https://snipboard.io/Ljc3PB.jpg



I enabled debug mode but it doesnt give any error logs..